# Base_url in CodeIgniter is not working

Tags: codeigniter

I have some form like this

```
<form action=<?php base_url('logincontroller/loginaction');?>  method=post >
```

by using  base_url as

```
$config['base_url']="localhost/testsite/index.php";
```

If I give like this it works just fine.

But I know it is not the correct way for giving base_url if i give base_url as.

```
$config['base_url']="localhost/testsite/";
```

Like this when i click submit it will come up with error that **page not found** 
what should i do to get it work?

Comment: Using `echo` in from action `php` code is good habit

Comment: Follow the docs. You missed URL scheme. (i.e. `$config['base_url']="http://localhost/testsite/";`). See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for more.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your `.htaccess` file in your project root folder. Here is the line that you need to add after `RewriteEngine` <kbd>On</kbd>:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And also enable `rewrite` in your apache by issuing this command in terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Finally, restart your apache service by this command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and then check the 'url' helper enabled in autoload.php line no : 67 file in config folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: thanks man its working 
but  i modified a line in .htaccess `RewriteBase /website/index.php`

Comment: Hmm... It is just to skipping `index.php` from the url .. BTW Welcome :)